# Should duplicate finding give reputation?

Tags: feature-request

- In some topics, intuitively I would guess C# or C++11 are among those, the gold digger times are over. Some old hats have earned a lot of reputation that may be hard to achieve by the half-baked.
- Deduplication is important. For everyone of us.

If you propose a duplicate which is then accepted, would it not be nice to get a Rep+ for that? Such that older tags can still give rise to newcomers, and such that the human deduplication machine gets fueled even better?

Maybe even more Rep+ if others agree on your dupe proposal?

(if there is already such system, it must be so insignificant that I did not recognize it; at the moment, I just dupe for goodwill)

Comment: I do not agree to this ...

Comment: Good idea for a badge, I think.  Conferring reputation for anything but questions and answers seems to cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: @RobertHarvey How so? The system rewards many other behaviors that furthers its goals.   If the goal is a single good answer for every question, why would conferring a few rep to the person who does the legwork of finding the duplicate cause problems?  Takes work off moderators' queues and achieves the goal in one fell swoop.

Comment: Also on MSE: [Reward finding duplicate questions, +10, +2, -5](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90620)

Comment: @JLH: `The system rewards many other behaviors` -- Yes, but not with reputation.  Suggested edits are the sole exception.

Answer (score 17):

I agree that awarding significant reputation would be a great way to encourage checking for duplicates.

However, reading answers to similar (but not duplicate) questions, this approach is not without practical problems:

1. Finding duplicates is not easy. I had a very similar idea to yours in June 2014 (about a month after you posted this), and after spending 10-15 minutes plowing through meta.so, couldn't find any questions that raised it. So, I posted [almost exactly the same question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261026/encourage-people-to-check-for-duplicates-before-answering), and within 10 minutes had several duplicate flags and ended up running away with my tail between my legs.
2. Flagging duplicates causes work for moderators. See [Should we reward helpful flags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/259886/should-we-reward-helpful-flags), which, funnily, is also flagged as a duplicate.
3. Correctly identifying something as a duplicate should also require feedback from the OP before the question is closed. The OP really should get the chance to say that yes, that other question (which they'd never seen) answers their problem as well. At the moment, close votes are one sided, although they can be reversed if the OP can make their case.

So, maybe the real question is.. "how do we redesign and streamline the de-duplication process in such a way that 1) the OP can accept the decisions, 2) those that go out and do the leg work of finding duplicates are rewarded, and 3) that requires minimal moderator input"?

Comment: The OP-acceptance shouldn't be required. Take a look how many questions don't have an accepted answer, because OP didn't care about the thread after creating it anymore. Propably the same phenomena will occur to duplicates... so you have questions reported as duplicates, but no more feedback from the OP.

Comment: Flagging duplicate is already possible and could also be a community choice instead of a moderators one. I can't see how it causes more work, than it does now. And shifting some moderators working force from *closing questions, which don't totally fit the SE-Platform* to *closing duplicates* wouldn't hurt StackExchange.

Comment: I've encountered OPs in the past who refuse to accept or even read duplicates because they are using the site as a coding service. But there's always the half a dozen of people willing to answer his question anyway.

Comment: Now an OP _can_ confirm that the other question solves their problem.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Now if the user who pointed the OP in the direction of the duplicate could receive a small reputation reward for doing so, then we'd have a system where the community is rewarded for this indisputably valuable behavior.