# Should we reward helpful flags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

Since accepted edits are rewarded with +2 rep, should a flag that's been deemed "helpful" also incur some form of reward (maybe +2 rep as well)?

This will help encourage new users to flag content that deserves a flag. And to help new users understand that flagging is not a "big scary" thing that only >100K users can do, *anyone* can flag.

Comment: And why do you think so? What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: @PatrickHofman To encourage users to flag content that deserves a flag. And to help new users not feel like flagging is a "big scary" thing that only >100K users can do.

Comment: New users are already (or at least should be) busy learning more basic stuff, like how to ask and answer. Or suggest edits correctly. We should not encourage them to start flagging mindlessly. We already spend a lot of time cleaning up their mess.

Comment: Users are already rewarded with badges for helpful flags.

Answer (score 21):

I strongly disagree. We don't want to encourage flagging with rep or badges more than we have now.

Why?

Because flagging most of the time means the precious time of mods are used. If someone takes flagging too easy (like a lot of users do with suggesting edits), the mods will be only handling flags.

Flags are for things that really can't stay here. You aren't looking for it, you bump in to it and have to respond. Unlike suggested edits where someone can walk down a question list and check for things needed to be edited.

Comment: Yes. The flag tooltip says: "flag this post *for serious problems or moderator attention*"

Comment: How about +2 for helpful flags, zero rep for incorrect type of flag even if the post should have been flagged, **-1** for unhelpful flags?

Comment: What about -10 for unhelpful flags?

Comment: If we did negative for unhelpful flags I'd go for -50 rep so newer users rarely use them

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Patrick but additionally you have to bare in mind that with the current system you get awarded a "Helpful Flag" when any question you flag is closed.

This means if I were to falsely flag a question that was a spam advertisement as "Too broad" and another user had correctly raised a "Spam" flag for it (a flag that gets a far faster response). I would get a helpful flag for it being closed from the "Spam" flag, even though my flag was incorrect.

If we were to reward users for raising flags. It should be for the *correct* flags.