# Please incentivize duplicate finding when gold badge closes as dup

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

This is closely related to [Should duplicate finding give reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255255/608639). However, it is missing an important use case. The use case is, a user moves against a question and proposes a duplicate. Then a gold badge closes the question as a duplicate of the proposed.

The gold badge holder should provide the necessary cross-checks to avoid some of the related problems, like incorrectly closing as a dup. A gold badge seems like he/she should contain some of the mob effect due to their subject matter expertise.

In this use case, finding a duplicate is the same as providing a correct answer. The person who finds the dup is rewarded instead of the [fastest gun in the west](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731/173448).

It might also slow down the flood of experienced users answering questions that should be closed as dups. Instead of long time users promulgating bad practices, the experienced users might start leading by example.

---

Here is an example of one: [Shell scripting not giving actual response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49562199/608639). @CharlesDuffy provided the subject matter expertise and performed the close after @MarcinOrlowski performed the research.

Comment: i mean... i like the idea, but i don't expect it to have any effect on people answering dupes for rep. It's just so much easier to answer, and you get so much more rep for doing so.

Comment: Nothing deters the FGITW problem quite like downvotes do. If you're too late to find a duplicate and close a question before it's answered, you know what to do next...

Comment: What do you mean by "*a user moves against a question*"?

Comment: You're saying that when a gold badge holder closes a question as a dupe of *someone else's* suggested duplicate target, that the *someone else* gets reputation? Or that the gold badge holder gets reputation?

Comment: I've had a question where I was absolutely sure there was a dupe (just due to how common the problem had to be) and in the time it took me to find it, there was an answer, with multiple upvotes, accepted, and then the OP closed the question as my proposed dupe *themselves* (and yes, it was a good dupe, and the "new" answer was nothing new). Net result: I lost out on potential rep, but the question is now properly signposted as a dupe, which does improve the site because the dupe did have other answers. This sort of stuff doesn't keep me up at night, but it *does* look weird, and wrong.

Comment: In principle, agreed. Separately, SO search needs to improve. It's strange that you have to *google* to find the best SO answer instead of using the SO search function. The work required to find and cross-check a dup is definitely worthy of reward. I suggest a +2 to all voting for dup.

Comment: probably worth noting that much less risky and less effort consuming suggestion has been hanging ignored by SE team for several months now, despite being apparently popular: [Could: “Possible duplicate of..” be given prominence for answering users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/352450/839601) This means chances of getting even bigger changes like suggested here are unfortunately vanishingly small

Comment: As someone's who's trying to earn a gold badge but can't find (m)any questions that are answerable, I very much like this idea. I cast _a lot_ more duplicate votes than I post answers. I dare say I've gotten quite good at it, too. I don't care much for reputation, but I'd very much like some progress toward the tag badge. Casting a lot of correct dupe votes is the best way to prove that you're ready to wield a hammer, isn't it? People should _absolutey_ be rewarded with some progress toward the tag hammer for finding correct duplicates.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You know what to do next: downvote the answer so multiple others can disagree with the downvote and counter it by upvoting, giving the answerer much more reputation than they would've gotten had you done nothing. Alternatively, drop the score of the post from +10 to +9, that'll show them.

Comment: on a meta meta level, content creation and content curation is two different activities.

Comment: I would only support a feature like this if it can be confirmed that the target dupe has actually helped the user.  For example, detect that OP has subsequently upvoted an answer on the target.  **It's important to only incentivize _accurate_ closing.**

Answer (score 46):

Eeeeeek!

> In this use case, finding a duplicate is the same as providing a correct answer.

Sure, if the duplicate is *accurate*.  If you have one or two, you have a high probability of accurately finding a correct dupe.  If you have *five*, then I genuinely don't believe you have a correct dupe at all.  I strongly maintain that one who closes with five different reasons is just piling on.

You *do* touch on the main problem here, which is:

> It might also slow down the flood of experienced users answering questions that should be closed as dups.

Searching for duplicates is a **broken system**.  ***Absolutely no incentive*** to reward dupe finders will work reliably, fairly or accurately until this is ***fixed***.  As an experienced user, it is an order of magnitude faster to type the answer than it is to go off hunting for a nuanced and ***very well hidden*** dupe.  That's not to say I wish to profit or proliferate this behavior; this is just how bad the system's gotten.

It's *so* bad I can't guarantee that even if I see an NPE question, when I type NPE that I'll get back the canonical NPE question for Java.  It takes extra time and effort to actually locate it.  Then there may be *other* unique types of NPEs; for example, if you get an NPE when you autowire a bean in Spring is ***not*** the same as your run-of-the-mill didn't-instantiate-an-object-and-now-I-wanna-dereference-it-NPE.  Think the current search system's going to be able to detect that context?   Well, it doesn't now.

No sense in rewarding anyone until the dupe-finding system is actually **working**.

---

What I mean by "working":

- A way to validate the accuracy of the dupe (likely a review queue with audits)
- A means to ensure that finding dupes isn't like finding a needle in a haystack
- A way for the OP to engage with the dupe to say, "No really this actually did answer my question," and a way for the community to override them when they *insist* that their NPE question is different than every other NPE question just like it

Remember:  we're not closing dupes because we're robots and that's what we should be doing.  We're closing dupes **in the service of the OP and others like them** so that they can find reliable answers.  If we're not keeping that in mind, we're wasting our time and energy.

Comment: I think you are conflating the problems of "finding the first duplicate" with "finding a duplicate". The request only asks for the second. It does not ask for the first. Overtime it would be nice to see a chain that builds a path back to the first duplicate. Interestingly, the "over time..." property is something the crowd posses. It is why wikis coverge on the right answer over time. Eventually the chain should emerge. (My apologies if I mis-parsed things).

Comment: How is the dupe-finding system related here? | Side note: [so] search tools being bad is a known problem, we expect people to search on Google and add `site:stackoverflow.com`. (...)

Comment: I agreed search is...poor. However, for yourself, you can do quite a bit to make it easy to find the common dups. One way is to just use your browser's bookmarks to collect a bookmark-folder full of common duplicate targets for the flags you regularly use. Doing so makes it trivial to find the common dups for a tag, once you've found it the first time. Personally, I have several sub-folders full of duplicate-targets, one folder per tag.

Comment: About "close with five different targets"... the question may be too broad.

Comment: "... an order of magnitude faster..." Truth. I actually favorite questions for the sole purpose of using them as dupe targets, because if I didn't favorite them, I'd never find them. There are even answers that *I know I wrote* that I have trouble finding...

Comment: I'm not sure the reasoning here makes sense. This answer reads to me as, roughly, *"finding duplicates is hard and requires significant time and effort, therefore it shouldn't be rewarded"*, which is... completely backwards? That it's hard and requires time and effort is a reason *to* reward it, surely?

Comment: @MarkAmery:  So how do you validate that the answer was accurate, then?  How do you ensure that even if a dupe is applied that it actually answers what question the OP was going for?  There's lots of gung-ho closures out there which don't directly answer the question, which makes duplicate closures *worse* than they should be.  Finding dupes alone is hard.  Making sure they're actually useful is even *harder*.  At a minimum, rewarding anyone for finding dupes should address both of these concerns in some way so that incentivization can be applied fairly.

Comment: @Makoto isn't that *exactly* why OP proposes only rewarding users after a gold-badge holder hammers the question? We trust them enough to unilaterally close the question, so the assumption is that they're closing accurately.

Comment: @mbrig:  Yeah, no.  Not when you have gold-badge users closing with four or five different dupes.  Don't get me wrong, I like the motivation, but there's nothing in this suggestion to actually ensure that we're doing the right thing by the OP when we close their question.

Comment: @Makoto FWIW, I agree with the entirety of your comment replying to me - but I think it presents a wholly different and orthogonal thesis to the one in your answer.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  It's another thought that popped into my head.  Half-sardonically, I stated that "it's broken" in the same fashion that the OP suggested that we get rewarded, in that I didn't really elaborate *what* was broken in the same vein that the OP didn't explain *how* we'd be rewarded.  I'll do us all a favor and update my answer explaining precisely how, and make my thesis less orthogonal.

Comment: "It takes extra time and effort to actually locate it" I actually have it cached in the drop-down entries :D Agreed with the general thought though, especially the part about finding a dupe being harder to write a decent answer many times...

Comment: What if there was some way to surface questions/answers that are common dupe targets in a tag? A list sorted by dupe targets instead of up votes.....

Comment: @NathanArthur:  That *barely* addresses searchability.  That's not a difficult query to author but then you run into the issues of dupe accuracy, which *again* is an issue; you're subject to how SO sees what you type in that text.  To make things worse, there are dupes on dupes on dupes in there which create *quite* a rabbit hole of tough-to-find information on the matter.

Comment: @Makoto Could a list like that condense the dupe tree? So if there was dupe > dupe > dupe > original, original would be credited with 3 dupes instead of one.

Comment: Well, there may have been a *reason* to do that that wasn't completely haphazard @NathanArthur.  Simplifying the problem of actual curating work with graphs and weird business rules still doesn't help the OP in finding the right answer.  Nested dupes would smell like answers needing to be combined instead of being chained dupes, or even better, someone would need to break the chain to demonstrate that these are two distinct problem spaces.

Comment: @Makato I'm not sure. If you could look at a list of questions in the same tag as a question, sorted by some combination of similarity to the current question, and frequency of being a (direct or indirect) dupe target, don't you think that might make finding the right dupe target easier?

Comment: @NathanArthur:  There's still curating work hidden among the leaves here.  The "right" duplicates may eventually rise to the top, but if there are enough "almost right" duplicates, we're going to want to amalgamate them into the "right" duplicates to ensure that the information we've got is the information that makes the most sense for anyone else looking for it.  I get it; it's easy to think about the search functionality and how the information can be conveyed.  It's **harder** to think about  the ultimate benefit the OP and others like them get out of it.

Comment: @NathanArthur:  It's important to take a breath and take a step back and remember why dupe closure was changed to be its own kind of closure in the first place.  **We want to _help_ the OP.**  We don't want them to feel like they're getting short-changed with this process.  So, it's important to note that there's still *work* to be done even after we identify dupes in curating this information so that others can truly keep benefiting from it.

Comment: @Makoto I completely agree. Good points.

Comment: for the sake of precision, [stats provided here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316682/839601) suggest that average difference is far from _order of magnitude_: "Median time to first close flag or vote: 7 minutes Median time to answer: 6 minutes"

Comment: @gnat: That's for questions **closed as duplicates** of the **top 100 targets**. Those are the ones that actually got closed, with the most memorable and/or easy-to-find dupe targets. Also, it's timed from *when the question was posted*, not when the answerer started typing or when the dupe-hunter started searching.

Comment: @Makoto, as a gold-badge holder, I regularly dupehammer overbroad questions by closing them with multiple preexisting matches; if they hadn't been dupehammered, the next choice is close-as-overbroad, which is *less* helpful to the OP. (I do occasionally add a community-wiki answer showing how to combine the techniques shown by the various duplicates, when it's reasonable to do so).

Answer (score 13):

I like the idea but I think it's difficult to avoid the next problem:

> The FFGITW *closing* problem

some non very ethical gold badge owners (I know a few...) would close as fast as possible with an irrelevant dupe just to get rep (this problem already exists *without* the incentive, when gold badge users, tired from the same questions, honestly tend to misread and close with wrong target, or even close a non-duplicate, it happens to me from time to time as well...)

What would happen next would be:

- other user(s) reopening
- another gold badge user editing the duplicate(s) & fixing the dupe target for a better one. Shouldn't *he* be the one to get rep?

If there were a way to reward closure *accuracy*... but closure is a *moderation* action, not an *answering* action.

In a more general way, something should be done to reward original answerers when closing as duplicate, like "The question has already an answer here..." and a message (maybe for users with not a lot of XP/rep on the site) stating "if some answers here fix your issue, please leave a vote".

Personal note: when I have to close as a duplicate, I tend to close with duplicates I *know* (I'm keeping a lot of bookmarks for the frequent ones for Python & C). Since I already answered a lot of questions, I have a tendency to close with original questions I answered to (of course if there's a better duplicate, it's not very ethical to do so, so questions have to be *very* close).

So if people following the current question follow the link to the original question, they'd be (maybe) more willing to drop a vote or two. And if the closer answered to one answer, then he/she can be rewarded. But that's up to the viewers.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers (and other times I've seen this discussion) touch on the fact that if we give rep for duplicates (e.g. in the same way we do for suggested edits) we'll have a *fastest gun in the west* for marking as duplicate or closing.

Would a simple solution to that problem not be to have the duplicate suggestions folded in among the answers? That way they could be upvoted, downvoted & accepted accordingly, so you wouldn't be rushing to find *any* duplicate, because if it really wasn't relevant, your dupe may get downvoted.

You could play with the reputation assigned, e.g. if a "real" answer gets 5 points for an upvote & 15 for an accept, maybe a "question is a duplicate" answer only gets 1 point for an upvote but 50 points for accept (for example, numbers off the top of my head.)

P.S.: See [this Meta.SE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198958/create-cw-answer-for-every-vote-to-close-as-duplicate-vote) for discussion of a similar suggestion.

Comment: @CodeCaster They could be displayed differently if they're from a potential duplicate.

Comment: You might have many answers on a question - do you display all of them, a few of them, only the top-voted one, do you group them by the question they came from? What if the answer(s) is/are really long? How long would it take to figure out what the question of the answer was actually asking? I like the basic idea here (and I'm sure I've seen it proposed before), but this definitely needs a suggestion to do this while avoiding the potential problems here.

Comment: Very related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/198958/create-cw-answer-for-every-vote-to-close-as-duplicate-vote

Comment: @CodeCaster if the original question has an answer, and that answer doesn't make sense for the duplicate question, then it's not an exact duplicate. It's a [borderline duplicate](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/29/handling-duplicate-questions/)

Comment: @DanHall Not necessarily. If an answer quotes the corresponding question, or builds upon code provided by the OP, folding it into even an exact duplicate can easily lead to an incomprehensible mess.

Comment: "[...] have the duplicates folded in among the answers? That way they could be upvoted, downvoted & accepted accordingly, so you wouldn't be rushing to find any duplicate, because if it really wasn't relevant, your dupe may get downvoted." -- and then the poor soul who answered the target question will get downvotes through no fault of their own, merely because someone else decided to cast a bad dupe vote.

Comment: Realise I probably didn't express myself very well above, but I meant as per the linked question that Shog mentioned — that just a link to the duplicate question would get added in (e.g. rather than the "Possible duplicate of…" *comment*, this would be an answer), rather than that all answers on the duplicate would get transposed on this question.

Comment: @anotherdave I took the liberty to edit the answer according to your comment (and remove my downvote accordingly). I'm still a bit ambivalent about presentation: it would be rather odd to have, in effect, link-only answers for that purpose. (That would be less of an issue, though, if the answers disappeared and were replaced by the usual banner once the question was closed.)

Answer (score 0):

The following is a strange idea that I really don't know how it would work out, but I think it's interesting enough to be worthwhile sharing.

---

Closing a question as a duplicate of another is actually "answering" the duplicate with, "See the question and answers here." What if duplicate suggestions created some kind of "answer" that could be voted on, instead of just a notice above the question?

Some possible advantages:

- Many questions aren't a literal duplicate of another but still are duplicates - it just requires reading and understanding the other Q&A to figure out how it applies. If the duplicate closer could expand upon why the duplicate applies, it could help the OP more.
- A lot of newcomers to Stack Overflow view closure of any kind as a personal attack or as the "mods" being out to get them. Presenting it as an answer might prevent hurt feelings.

Definite drawbacks / points that would have to be worked out:

- This would be a lot of engineering work to implement and add to the site.
- Would the "answer" block other answers?
- Would the "answer" be only for the person who posted the original suggestion, blocking out all other users? This would be an even worse FGITW problem.
- Should reputation be the same as with regular answers?

Maybe the "answer" should be a kind of "community wiki" where reputation is shared amongst the closers.

Comment: Wouldn't that make duplicate targets subjective, rather than objective? If the goal of duplicates is to concentrate the best content in canon Q&A's, a duplicate that can actually be rated (based on what? its quality of its compatibility with the question?) seems to drift away from that goal.

Comment: Some of the history on this suggestion: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198958/135695 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166844/135695

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm unsurprised that someone thought of the idea before. I'm glad to see that there has been significant discussion and thought put into the idea already. I wonder what the status of the feature-request is, though (my guess would be *put-off-indefinitely* because more details need to be fleshed out and it's a lot of work to implement)