# What to do when a high-reputation user answers a lot of duplicates?

Tags: discussion, answers, duplicate-questions, dupehammer

I noticed that a 70k+ python gold badge owner answered 5 blatant duplicate [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) questions the last 4 days (today was the worst, it was dupe after dupe) with - of course - a lot of votes (and having looked into this user other answers, I'd say that finding duplicates for a big part of those answers shouldn't be too much of a problem...)

Those duplicates weren't particularly good questions either (all negative scores), so not really worth acting as a "signpost" either...

Of course everyone gets "caught" answering duplicates, but when you have some experience on the site (and a gold badge) you *know* that such or such question has been asked many times.

**I'm not asking for a nth feature that will never be implemented** (like incentiving users to close instead of answer, that overcomplex stuff), but should I:

- downvote, explaining that they shouldn't do that: *always possible, but doesn't have a very positive effect plus starts a war*
- flag such posts for moderation (explaining the abuse): *would that be a valid flag case?*
- be faster when hammering the posts (so it's my fault if it takes me 1 minute to find the duplicate using google): *works, but time consuming*
- answer faster than them to get more rep myself (deliberately provocative): *I'm not getting rep like this, no way.*

Related:

- [Reputable people keep answering duplicates - What's the solution?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357021/reputable-people-keep-answering-duplicates-whats-the-solution)
- [What to do when a high rep user answers a low-quality, off-topic or duplicate question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-answers-a-low-quality-off-topic-or-duplicate-qu)

Comment: Will this witch hunt ever stop?

Comment: Close the duplicates, basically. Bout all there is to it. Downvoting a high quality answer because it's posted on a duplicate doesn't seem all that useful (even though it might feel good)

Comment: [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365254/1079354)

Comment: Imo you can downvote if you wish. One of the most valid reasons for downvoting imo is because an answer is not useful, and rehashing a solution to a known problem is not that useful, even if you do it well.

Comment: @rene I'm _not_ asking for new features, that's written in the question. I'm asking what to do, and if mod flagging is an option.

Comment: Maybe you need to expand in your question how flagging those answers is not targeting the user?

Comment: but I _want_ to target the user. At least the duplicate target is good. thanks.

Comment: From the top answer on the dupe: "The more people *rep whore*, the more this just invalidates the usefulness of rep as being a correlation of programming acuity. This will mean the site will lose credibility in the long run, as a programming resource or for career prospects." Sums up the situation well. By allowing people to accumulate reputation for the sake of doing so, we're cheapening the entire purpose of the reputation in the first place.

Comment: Sure... but what do we do about it? downvoting answers in this case is a drop in the bucket and will not change the fact that they are gaining rep from continuing this trend. It's a losing battle. If you want to enact change in this scenario, more than casting downvotes is required.

Comment: I've reached out to this particular user in the past. They do not seem receptive to feedback nor do they care that it is a duplicate. This seems like a pathological problem with a lot of repwfarmers that nothing short of a mod message fill fix. However, there is nothing inherently against guidelines with answering duplicates, so I fear there is nothing you can do but beat them to the punch with closure. At least there's more to reputation than the number.

Comment: @KevinB, yes, and I try to have the Q&A deleted altogether as well. Sometimes it works. But there are some strict rules. And if the question is good, well, let's not punish the asker and leave it be

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ there are a lot of high rep python users (like you and others I'm not going to mention but that I highly respect) answering good questions which _aren't_ blatant duplicates (well, 99% of the time) and get well deserved rep for that. no need to lower answering useless dupes to get some rep, even in c tag...

Comment: Conversely, what should we do when reputable people keep marking questions as a duplicate? I have been in a long-running dispute with this user active in regex tag who treats others as if he's the owner of the tag. I should ask some gold badge holders to confirm his misbehaviors. Not sure if it will change something.

Comment: @revo If the duplicate closures are justified, then there is no reason to do anything. Duplicate question really shouldn't be answered in the first place. As someone with a badge in the tag, you should be able to decide whether it is justified or not. If not, approach the user. If it still continues, bring the issue up on meta.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ you mean like "link to the posts so the user is crucified on the public place" ? as much as I'd like to do that, not sure if it's appropriate.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth When I downvote such an answer I get one or two downvotes minutes later. What should I do in this case?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Honestly, 95% of the question in C tag is homework dump about `printf`, `scanf`, invalid pointer use... I've already put C tag in the ignore list ;)

Comment: @revo not much. Personally, I tend to wait for the post to gather 2 extra close votes, so it's not obvious I'm the downvoter. But you can't do much about revenge downvotes except take them like a man (or woman, person, or other being)

Comment: @liliscent on the C tag, some 100k+ or 200k+ users keep answering those questions too. With my poor c gold (1060 points) I close a lot of those... I answer very rarely. It took me forever to get gold...

Comment: @revo don't necessarily downvote (or wait a few hours). Just close & vote to delete.

Comment: i've noticed different ways that some users oviously look more for points than usefulness, from this, to copy/paste your answer and comment right away to the OP asking to "accept if useful" so that the interaction causes the copied answer to be accepted instead. I personnally gave up the fight, and stick to helping people, but in a way that's too bad. Without privileges, you feel like Don Quichotte fighting wind mills..

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth That would be a working trick. But in my case he thinks I'm the only person who does this to him. So it doesn't matter to wait for others to vote. Most of the time, when I get a downvote I check his reputation and see he got one recently.

Comment: @Kaddath then get privileges, delete votes, dupe hammer. Now you stand a chance. You can visit SOCVR as well to post your close/delete requests if they are legitimate.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I really don't care about receiving downvotes but it's annoying when you find a pattern that someone follows to downvote you.

Comment: agreed, then when encountering this user, _don't_ downvote, don't vote to close & propose the duplicate at SOCVR. If it's a good duplicate, you'll get help.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Now the problem is not me. The problem is his assumptions whenever he gets a downvote (he thinks I did it while I didn't) and then downvotes one or two of my posts randomly.

Comment: you should flag that, then, explaining the situation (but take notes of the downvoted posts). A SE employee will be able to tell that the same person serially downvoted you (under the radar)

Comment: Yeah and I have been flagging with a thorough explanation of situation. I have one of them *pending* for near three weeks. Two months ago one moderator, kindly, replied *I've forwarded this onto the CMs to investigate, it does appear to be targeted. May take a week or two to process.* and since then I have been in the same trouble.

Comment: @revo: it takes time, because CM have a lot on their plate, but it will be processed eventually.

Comment: I wonder what will happen if they find that it is targeted? A reversal or something that prevents such misbehaviors from the same user?

Comment: I'm surprised to see you post this, as you left [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315936/what-to-do-when-a-high-rep-user-answers-a-low-quality-off-topic-or-duplicate-qu#comment589346_315939)

Comment: unfortunately, you just get reversal. But the other user knows that there was manual reversal, so they'll be more cautious next time (hopefully)

Comment: As a high-rep user, I'm tempted to answer this question, but it's a duplicate.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre meaning you were aware of the question. target dupe

Comment: no, I added the reference in my post after someone pointed it out to me. Check the timeline. the question has already been closed as a duplicate (of the wrong question), then reopened