# A new take on dup-finding incentive

Tags: feature-request, dupehammer

I want to suggest something a bit different than these (there are a ton more, including FGITW questions):

[Give an incentive for finding duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37466/give-an-incentive-for-finding-duplicate-questions)

[Should duplicate finding give reputation?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255255/should-duplicate-finding-give-reputation)

**I am not suggesting rep-for-dup finding.** (<strike>though I would like to see rep gained on these Q/As rolled back, mine own included</strike> [Servy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375984/a-new-take-on-dup-finding-incentive#comment642535_375984) convinced me this is bad).

What I suggest is a separate, **successful dup-close counter/score** in the profile (maybe a badge for some score).

**Award +1 for score if user is the first to vote as duplicate, and the question is eventually marked as a duplicate.**

Further more, I suggest **awarding the hammer according to this score**, in addition to the language badge. Successful means the question was marked a duplicate - future edits to remove the flag are immaterial, as at the time of the vote the question was marked a duplicate.

If someone proves he cares enough to find dups, and that they are capable according to the community - through some minimal score they achieve, they should get the hammer.

**Yes**, I think more people should wield it (I do not think I am one of those by the way, I fail way too often to identify dups). **No**, a few over-zealous users should not be cause to prevent this power (there are moderators to deal with behavior problems).

**A point to consider**

You theoretically can get a 1000 rep on a language by answering only duplicates. Having 4 more people/a hammer agree with you on a duplicate some large amount of times seems like at least as good a metric for a good closinator.

Comment: What counts as, "capable"?  How is the system supposed to figure that out?  And what happens when something is closed as a dupe, but then later reopened?

Comment: My inner cynic says it'd be more fruitful to remove all gained rep from a question that gets closed as a duplicate, from both the question and all answers. That could be automated too.

Comment: @fbueckert I thought it was clear "<score> > 100" or s ome other chosen number. I'll edit it in. This is since the score is an implication the community agrees. Actually, I think there should be a negative for something not voted a dup after some time.

Comment: @usr2564301 It's unlikely to be successful as it creates too many perverse incentives.  Incentives for people to vote to close questions someone they don't like has answered, even if not a good duplicate, and incentives for people who have answered a question to reopen it even if it's actually a duplicate (the more problematic of the two).

Comment: @Servy That second one is a good point, I did not consider - I guess rep should be taken out of the equation.

Comment: @Servy: consider that there are currently *no* good reasons to *not* answer a clear duplicate(1), and usually some minute rep to gain. (1) Other than "maintaining the quality of SO", which is clearly not that important for those who do answer.

Comment: @usr2564301 That's a bit harsh - I sometimes answer dups by mistake - it's just too time consuming if you are not in a walking Wiki in the specific tags.

Comment: @usr2564301 I'm aware of that.  But likewise, there's also not much in the way of incentives currently for someone to reopen a duplicate once they've answered it.

Comment: A question where someone dupe-voted and that doesn't get closed doesn't mean that the close-vote was wrong. 1) Op edited the question to clarify why it's not a duplicate. That's often the case for low-effort and unclear questions 2) There simply weren't enough people to close-vote. That's especially a problem in tags without many gold badge holder. A lot of votes time out nowadays. The close vote queue is at >8k for years now.

Comment: @BDL You are saying there is no chance to identify "capable" dup finders?

Comment: Or perhaps - just remove the negative part.

Comment: @kabanus: I want to say that your metric to identifying them has problems. There might be a good way although I don't know of any. As it stands now, the metric could as well have a negative effect because people in low-volume tags stop dupe-closing in order to keep there records clean.

Comment: @BDL Yea that makes sense - I removed the part about negative points. You can only come closer to getting the hammer this way. I think If 5 people/a hammer agree with you than that is good enough to give you at least a positive +1 in the metric (at the time of writing the question is what matters, of course the question may be fixed, but this should not affect your "proper" identification of the original version.)

Comment: Actually - this should only be true if you are the **first** voter. This discussion is quite helpful.

Comment: @HansPassant I am not sure how to read that - is that an insult? should I not post suggestions on meta (and this is not my first)? Also, yes - it seems like lately the questions are a grind.

Comment: @kabanus basically... When you gamify a system, there comes a point where you feel "playing the game" has no more purpose because there are no more worth-while rewards to encourage you to continue. I doubt it was meant as an insult.

Comment: @KevinB I thought you only got presents at 100k? j/k I guess that is a valid point, though why "beware" of me? Reads like someone thinks I am a zealot. It also feels somewhat presumptuous to actually accuse someone of  something like that, but of course, it is just a feeling.

Comment: @kabanus, Don't take it personally, this is a typical response from someone who has "seen it all".. "Beware of the eternal pessimist". I think you're right, of course, no need to skirt the issue by hypothesizing motives.

Comment: @usr2564301 Depends. Duplicate questions can be useful too (as signpost), duplicate answers -- definitely not.

Comment: @Servy Of course wrong close vote can be fixed bythe community...

Comment: @user202729 The community has major problems closing questions as it is.  There are already way too many close worthy questions for them to be properly closed.  Add in a lot of people going around reopening questions that were correctly closed becomes a big problem.  Either attention is given to those posts, and others don't get that attention, or they don't get enough attention to correct the problem.  Either way, it becomes a major issue.  Now if the people actively moderating content were able to adequately review posts already, that wouldn't be an issue, but we're no where near that.

Answer (score 6):

The system of Stack Overflow is predicated heavily on trust.  The system, however, is not capable of divining trust; it must get feedback from others on it.

A gold tag badge is indicative of a level of trust bestowed upon someone in the community; their answers are acceptable by a large amount of people (with an average of 5 points per answer for 200 answers) and they can be given extra privileges.

This also makes this level of trust auditable and *revokable* as tag badges are the *only* kind of badge you can lose as a natural consequence.

If you're magically awarded tag points based on dupe closure, there's no real audit trail or natural way to revoke the privilege, which gets *scary*.  A user could never answer a Java question in their life and still have the ability to unilaterally close them as dupes.  Not a fan.

Comment: If they never answer, but always finds duplicates - isn't that at least as good as having 1000 rep on a language? I would say it is an even better audit - you can gain rep from answering only duplicates!

Comment: How can I trust you know what you're doing if you never actually *answer* a question?  It's kinda like hiring a baker despite never seeing them actually bake a cake yet they're a notorious cake judge.

Comment: Disagree. Restaurants critics **are not** chefs in general (same for movie, art, game, whatever critics). You can trust me since I managed to convince 100 times 4 more people or another hammer that my suggested dup is real.

Comment: Yeah, but you refuse to bake brownies, so...

Comment: Tangential, but *"an average of 5 points per answer for 200 answers"* is *already* a low bar, not indicative of deep knowledge or high answer quality. Most of what a gold badge measures is that you answer lots of questions. I've always been uncomfortable with using gold badges as a way to gatekeep special privileges for precisely that reason.

Comment: @MarkAmery:  Yes, it's a low bar.  Which is why I think lowering it any *further* would be a mistake.  At a minimum it does indicate that hey, you're participating on the site.  Answering lots of questions does indicate that you have *some* understanding of how the site works.

Comment: So I just have really good taste buds? I actually think I raised the bar, the more that I consider this  (how many successful first vote dups an average user will get over their first year? 1? 2?). The more I think about it my suggested incentive is actually not strong enough.

Comment: Right, so here's the deal.  Your highest tag badge is Python, with 240 score across 277 posts.  You're *averaging* 1.05 points per post which indicates that your answers aren't *that* quality.  You should work on that as opposed to looking for a shortcut.

Comment: Disregarding the ad-hominem, how many dups did I get first? I really think you are missing the "correcter" metric here. I am not that quality, but even more-so in finding duplicates.

Comment: I see posts closed with inappropriate dupes all the time.  I don't think it's right to suggest that a dupe closing is permanent or even absolute in this fashion.

Comment: OK, so I guess we disagree.

Comment: @Makoto Low average scores on posts can indicate someone posting in niche topics just as much as someone posting low quality content.  (I say this without having looked at said posts to determine how popular the topics in question are.)

Comment: In what way is the badge revocable? You mean that if other users downvote you enough for the score to drop below 1000, or can moderators manually revoke the gold badge if someone keeps hammering questions incorrectly?

Comment: @user000001:  If you've *just* got the post and you've been largely getting it based on poor questions which are subject for removal from the site, then you can lose a tag badge that way.  Moderators can take the privilege away from you individually, but I've not heard of any instance when that's happened to this point.

Comment: @user000001 It's more likely that posts of yours with a high score would be either deleted or retagged, than having been downvoted enough to lose the badge, although technically any of those are possible.  Votes can also be retracted, which is notable in the case of serial vote reversals, (either automatically or by a moderator) which could result in significant drops of a tag score.

Comment: A solution to this problem would be that rep gained this way do not count towards a tag badge.